# Add appointment to Someones Elses Shared Outlook Calendar Using VBA in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I am having difficulty adding an appointment to a coworkers calendar that they shared with me. The problem appears to be in the calendar reference. My appointments keep adding to their main default calendar while I am trying to add them to a separate shared calendar named "Study Schedule". I am running office 365.

```
    Dim olApp                 As Outlook.Application
    Dim olappt                As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim bAppOpened            As Boolean
    Dim myNamespace           As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim objRecip              As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim strName               As String
    Dim myFolder              As Outlook.Folder
 

    Const olAppointmentItem = 1
            
            On Error Resume Next
            Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Err.Clear
            Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            bAppOpened = False  ' Outlook was not already running, started it
            Else
                bAppOpened = True   ' Outlook was already running
            End If
           ' On Error GoTo Error_Handler
            
            ' Get Study Schedule Folder Location
            Set myNamespace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
            Set objRecip = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("John Doe")
                objRecip.Resolve
    ' I believe the problem is in the two lines of code below as I try to reference non default folder (shared from john doe)            
                Set myFolder = myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objRecip, olFolderCalendar)
                Set myFolder = myFolder.Folders("Study Schedule") 
                myFolder.Display
                Set olappt = myFolder.Items.Add
                'Set olappt = myNewFolder.Items.Add
                With olappt
                            .AllDayEvent = True
                            .Start = ScheduledDate
                            .Subject = StudyName
                            .Body = "Study has been scheduled." & vbCr & _
                                vbCr & _
                                "Calendar Assigned: " & myFolder & vbCr & _
                                "Schedule Entry ID: " & ScheduleEntryID & vbCr & _
                                "Study Name: " & StudyName & vbCr & _
                                "Scheduled Date: " & ScheduledDate & vbCr & _
                                vbCr & _
                                "Principle Investigator: " & PrincipleInvestigator & vbCr & _
                                "Order Placed By: " & OrderPlacedBy & vbCr & _
                                vbCr & _
                                "Species: " & Spec

ies & vbCr & _
                            "Strain: " & Strain & vbCr & _
                            "Sex " & Sex & vbCr & _
                            "Age: " & Age & vbCr & _
                            "Weight: " & Weight & " Kg" & vbCr & _
                            "Quantity : " & Quantity & vbCr & _
                            vbCr & _
                            "Study Information: " & StudyDescription & vbCr & _
                            vbCr & _
                            "This Event was auto generated from the Scheduling Assistant and In-Vivo Database."
                        .Location = ""
                        .Display
               '         .Save
                   '    .Send
            End With

    ... Rest of Code
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Consider `Option Explicit` at the top to be mandatory.

Comment: Consider `On Error GoTo 0` mandatory, to return to normal error handling, as soon as possible after `On Error Resume Next`. Place `On Error GoTo 0` where you now have the commented `On Error GoTo Error_Handler`. If you cannot clear up any errors now they are visible edit the question with more information.

Comment: Did you check permissions on the shared calendar? Pause execution at after first myfolder assignment and check the content of myFolder.Folders.

Comment: Hello, They listed me as the owner of the Calendar and gave me full read/write/delete permissions. I added a msgbox after the myfolder and myfolder.folders. Both are referencing their default "Calendar - John Doe". I am trying to reference "John Doe - Study Schedule"

Comment: You reference the folder named "Calendar - John Doe". You bypass the error referencing the "Study Schedule" calendar. Bypassing the error means the reference to myFolder remains the same. No good comes of not knowing how to use `On Error Resume Next`.

Comment: Thanks niton, I applied your on Error GoTo 0 and was able to confirm that the error is indeed coming from the step where i try to reference the study schedule calendar. Using msgboxes i was able to determine the following are referenced with my code: myNamespace = Mapi , Recipient = John Doe , myFolder = John Doe - Calendar , myFolder.Folders("Study Schedule") = The attempted operation Failed, an object could not..... I am unfortunately still stuck trying to get the "Study Schedule" calendar reference correct. Please let me know if there is any other information i can provide to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around. The code I ended up going with is posted Below. Thank you everyone for the rapid responses! I really appreciated the help.

```
 Dim olApp                 As Outlook.Application
        Dim olappt                As Outlook.AppointmentItem
        Dim bAppOpened            As Boolean
        Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
        Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder
        Dim objPane As Outlook.NavigationPane
        Dim objModule As Outlook.CalendarModule
        Dim CalFolder As Outlook.Folder
        
        Const olAppointmentItem = 1
        
        On Error Resume Next
        Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        bAppOpened = False  ' Outlook was not already running, started it
        Else
            bAppOpened = True   ' Outlook was already running
        End If
       ' On Error GoTo Error_Handler
        On Error GoTo 0
      
        Set objPane = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer.NavigationPane
        Set objModule = objPane.Modules.GetNavigationModule(olModuleCalendar)
        
            With objModule.NavigationGroups
            For g = 1 To .Count
            Set objGroup = .Item(g)
            
                For i = 1 To objGroup.NavigationFolders.Count
                Set objNavFolder = objGroup.NavigationFolders.Item(i)
        
        If objNavFolder = "Study Schedule" Or objNavFolder = "John Doe - Study Schedule" Then
        Set CalFolder = objNavFolder.Folder
        
        MsgBox CalFolder
        End If
        Next
        Next
        End With
        
        Set olappt = CalFolder.Items.Add
        
        With olappt
                    .Display
                    .AllDayEvent = True
                    .Start = ScheduledDate
                    .Subject = StudyName
                    .Body = "Study has been scheduled." & vbCr & _
                        vbCr & _
                        "Schedule Entry ID: " & ScheduleEntryID & vbCr & _
                        "Study Name: " & StudyName & vbCr & _
                        "Scheduled Date: " & ScheduledDate & vbCr & _
                        vbCr & _
                        "Principle Investigator: " & PrincipleInvestigator & vbCr & _
                        "Order Placed By: " & OrderPlacedBy & vbCr & _
                        vbCr & _
                        "Species: " & Species & vbCr & _
                        "Strain: " & Strain & vbCr & _
                        "Sex " & Sex & vbCr & _
                        "Age: " & Age & vbCr & _
                        "Weight: " & Weight & " Kg" & vbCr & _
                        "Quantity : " & Quantity & vbCr & _
                        vbCr & _
                        "Study Information: " & StudyDescription & vbCr & _
                        vbCr & _
                        "This Event was auto generated from the Scheduling Assistant and In-Vivo Database."
                    .Location = ""
                    .Display
           '         .Save
               '    .Send
        End With
```

Answer (score 0):

It is likely the shared calendar is at the same level as the default calendar.

```
' For a folder at the same level as the default calendar
'  navigate up then back down
Set myFolder = myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objRecip, olFolderCalendar)
Set myFolder = myFolder.Parent.Folders("Study Schedule")
```